# update swarm when a new build I ready from docker hub

Tags: dockerhub

Reading [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/) regarding webhooks is it possible to have a swarm service to update when a new build is ready?

That is via automated-build.

If you can just help with a direction.